# Error while pushing Flask Web App on Heroku- "Requested runtime is not available for this stack (heroku-18)."

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a **Flask** Web Application for Image Classification (Thus using **TensorFlow**) on Heroku. On attempting to deploy using "*git push Heroku master*", I get the following error message:

> remote: -----> Python app
> Requested runtime (**Flask==1.1.2** remote:
> **Jinja2==2.11.2** remote: **tensorflow==2.3.0** remote: **Werkzeug==1.0.1**) is
> not available for this stack (heroku-18).

I am stuck here. How do we go about deploying a Flask application that uses TensorFlow on Heroku, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a runtime.txt in our main folder and write the python version you are using, like

```html
python-3.7.10
```